# Gravity form currency code injection (js)

Tags: forms, gravity

I am using Gravity form but not using the currency setting.

Anyway, it is still injecting js code in the code, see below:

var gf_global = {"gf_currency_config":{"name":"U.S. Dollar","symbol_left":"$","symbol_right":"","symbol_padding":"","thousand_separator":",","decimal_separator":".","decimals":2,"code":"USD"},"base_url":"https:\/\/trystant1.sg-host.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/gravityforms","number_formats":[],"spinnerUrl":"https:\/\/trystant1.sg-host.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/gravityforms\/images\/spinner.svg","version_hash":"6ec2b1378a7918ce93decf7e2062a9d6","strings":{"newRowAdded":"New row added.","rowRemoved":"Row removed","formSaved":"The form has been saved.  The content contains the link to return and complete the form."}};  var gform_i18n = {"datepicker":{"days":{"monday":"Mo","tuesday":"Tu","wednesday":"We","thursday":"Th","friday":"Fr","saturday":"Sa","sunday":"Su"},"months":{"january":"January","february":"February","march":"March","april":"April","may":"May","june":"June","july":"July","august":"August","september":"September","october":"October","november":"November","december":"December"},"firstDay":1,"iconText":"Select date"}}; var gf_legacy_multi = {"12":"1","18":"","19":"","20":"1","17":"","7":"1","14":"","4":"1","3":"","16":"","10":"1","15":"","13":"1","1":"1"}; var gform_gravityforms = {"strings":{"invalid_file_extension":"This type of file is not allowed. Must be one of the following:","delete_file":"Delete this file","in_progress":"in progress","file_exceeds_limit":"File exceeds size limit","illegal_extension":"This type of file is not allowed.","max_reached":"Maximum number of files reached","unknown_error":"There was a problem while saving the file on the server","currently_uploading":"Please wait for the uploading to complete","cancel":"Cancel","cancel_upload":"Cancel this upload","cancelled":"Cancelled"},"vars":{"images_url":"https:\/\/trystant1.sg-host.com\/wp-content\/plugins\/gravityforms\/images"}};

And it duplicate the var gf_global lines like 50 times...

Does anybody know how to get rid of this script?

Thanks

I tried to search for a setting to disable but can't find it